# how to update quantity in cart in react

Tags: reactjs, cart

I'm trying to update my cart with qty as qty_added in the cart.

how can I update qty_added in a cart rather than push the same item again in the cart? I just want to update qty_added and not push the product and qty_added (as objects) again in the cart.

```
 for every product to add there is a button that is updating the context.

   <button  className="btn btn-sm btn-warning" onClick={()=>{this.context.addToCart(buildingtoy,1)}}>Add to Cart</button>


//routes.js//

  addToCart:(product,qty)=>{
            let cart=this.state.cart;
            cart.map((c)=>{
                let ncart=[];
                if(c.product.id==product.id)

                {
                   c.qty_added+=qty;
                   ncart.push(c);
                   console.log(ncart)
                }  


            cart.push({

                product:product,
                qty_added:qty

            });  


        this.setState({

                cart:cart

            })

                        }); 


                console.log('qty in cart ',qty,'productid',product.id)  
                console.log(cart)
                localStorage.setItem('cart',JSON.stringify(cart))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call addToCart every time but when you call it, check if the product exists by doing an id  match. If it doesn’t then add it with quantity of 1. If it does, then increase the quantity of the product by doing `quantity = quantity +=1`

edit

your problem is here:

```
        cart.push({
            product:product,
            qty_added:qty
        });
```

you need to get the whole state of the cart `object`. and then find the item, update it and then overwrite the state of the cart object with the new object

Comment: yes thats what i did .Its updating qty_added in cart but along with that its also pushing in cart same product again. how can i stop adding in cart if id is same

Comment: @shruti added more

Comment: I think it wud be the same thing if I create a new object then update the state with the new object

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `push()` that simply add in existing array.

Use `concat()` function that returns a new array containing the values of the joined old array.

you can also use `useReducer` hook from `react` and use as shown in the image to update cart logic

[image]

```
const [cartState,dispatchCartAction]= useReducer(cartContext,defaultCartState)
```